# EXPO.io push notification on android not working

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, expo

I am having some issues sending push notifications to android using expo

In order to make sure I had a clean push token, I deleted the app from the device and reinstalled the app(standalone)
This created a brand new push token.
All fine.

I have then tried to dispatch the push notification using postman:

```
{
  "to": "ExponentPushToken[dgbW_nEUW-Yp9WpWiLpBIu]",
  "sound": "default",
  "body": "Hello world!"
}
```

This is what I got:

```
{
    "data": {
        "status": "ok"
    }
}
```

At this point I did not received the push notification.

When I tried to send another one, this is what I got:

```
{
    "data": {
        "status": "error",
        "message": "SNS failed to send the notification (reason: EndpointDisabled, status code: 400).",
        "details": {
            "error": "DeviceNotRegistered",
            "sns": {
                "statusCode": 400,
                "reason": "EndpointDisabled",
                "__message": "Endpoint is disabled"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a clue what could be happening? Is this a bug?
(ios is working fine)

Answer (score -1):

every post  with postman has a title like https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send.

Be sure to change in your App.js "const PUSH_ENDPOINT = https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send